# Mint and Ubuntu live disks, meltdown and spectre

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, livecd

Have the Mint and Ubuntu live disks been updated with the meltdown and spectre mitigations yet? I have no hard disk access, so can only use live disk CD. Thanks.

Comment: The new ubuntu 17.10 (w/ fix for the Lenovo bricking issue) do not have anti-meltdown patches [source: some Jupiter Broadcasting podcast a few days ago, don't remember which one/when]. No idea about mint.

Comment: Check your kernel version and refer to this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/415479/153195